# How to get the consolidated ServiceID with the sum of File Size associated with over an year

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014, join, temporary-tables

Can anyone please help me on below to get the consolidated ServiceID with the sum of File Size associated with it over an year.

**Complete Code** (For reference)

```
If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp1
End

GO

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp2') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp2
End
GO

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp3') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp3
End

GO

If(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp4') Is Not Null)
Begin
    Drop Table #Temp4
End
GO

SELECT *
INTO #Temp1
FROM
(
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ServiceName,2,3) AS ServiceID 
      , FileTotalSize as FileSize 
      ,year = '1980' from table1 
    ) a

--1981
SELECT *
INTO #Temp2
FROM
(
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ServiceName,2,3) AS ServiceID 
      , FileTotalSize as FileSize 
      ,year = '1981'
        from table2 
    ) b

--1982
SELECT *
INTO #Temp3
FROM
(
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ServiceName,2,3) AS ServiceID 
      , FileTotalSize as FileSize
      ,year = '1982' from table3
) c

--1983

SELECT *
INTO #Temp4
FROM
(
SELECT 
SUBSTRING(ServiceName,2,3) AS ServiceID 
      , FileTotalSize as FileSize 
      ,year = '1983' from table4 
    ) d


select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize1 from #Temp1
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize2 from #Temp2
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize3 from #Temp3
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize4 from #Temp4
```

**Below are the 4 queries existing in #temp tables I finally worked and their outputs:**

```
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize1 from #Temp1
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize2 from #Temp2
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize3 from #Temp3
select ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY year ASC) AS ID,ServiceID,year,FileTotalSize AS FileSize4 from #Temp4
```

**Output of the above 4 queries:**

[image]

**My Question :** How can I get the below output using the above 4 queries ? Please help me , the way I need to join . I tried my way to join them but sure it is wrong so reached out for help.

[image]

Thank you

Comment: Is your data static for years 1980, 1981, 1982 and 1983 or will you query serve up random years?

Comment: Hi @ScottHodgin , data is not static , the values for filesize differs for years . Can be more entries of ServiceID as well.

Comment: Please update your question to include actual table definitions and sample data in the form of `INSERT` statements so we don't have to type this stuff up ourselves.  To be clear, your data can have more than 4 distinct years?  For example, you could have unlimited number of years?

Comment: Sorry for that , I will include now . and there are only 4 distinct years but the data can differ , I mean the filesizes over each year because of multiple service IDs each year.

Comment: @ScottHodgin Updated my question with complete code block for reference

Comment: I tried running your code block in a new query window and received errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how this could be done.

```
Declare @Query1 table (id int, ServiceID int, Year int, FileSize1 int)
Declare @Query2 table (id int, ServiceID int, Year int, FileSize1 int)
Declare @Query3 table (id int, ServiceID int, Year int, FileSize1 int)
Declare @Query4 table (id int, ServiceID int, Year int, FileSize1 int)

insert into @Query1(id,ServiceID,Year,FileSize1) values
(1,121,1980,10),
(2,122,1980,20),
(3,123,1980,30),
(4,121,1980,40)

insert into @Query2(id,ServiceID,Year,FileSize1) values
(1,121,1981,10),
(2,122,1981,20),
(3,123,1981,30),
(4,123,1981,40)

insert into @Query3(id,ServiceID,Year,FileSize1) values
(1,121,1982,10),
(2,122,1982,20),
(3,124,1982,30),
(4,125,1982,40)

insert into @Query4(id,ServiceID,Year,FileSize1) values
(1,123,1983,10),
(2,121,1983,20),
(3,122,1983,30),
(4,121,1983,40)

;With _cte as
(
select ServiceID,Year,FileSize1 as FileSize1 from @Query1 
union all
select ServiceID,Year,FileSize1 as FileSize1 from @Query2 
union all
select ServiceID,Year,FileSize1 as FileSize1 from @Query3 
union all
select ServiceID,Year,FileSize1 as FileSize1 from @Query4 
)

select ServiceID,
sum(case when year = 1980 then FileSize1 end) as FileSize_1980,
sum(case when year = 1981 then FileSize1 end) as FileSize_1981,
sum(case when year = 1982 then FileSize1 end) as FileSize_1982,
sum(case when year = 1983 then FileSize1 end) as FileSize_1983
 from _cte
group by ServiceID
```

---

```
| ServiceID | FileSize_1980 | FileSize_1981 | FileSize_1982 | FileSize_1983 |
|-----------|---------------|---------------|---------------|---------------|
| 121       | 50            | 10            | 10            | 60            |
| 122       | 20            | 20            | 20            | 30            |
| 123       | 30            | 70            | NULL          | 10            |
| 124       | NULL          | NULL          | 30            | NULL          |
| 125       | NULL          | NULL          | 40            | NULL          |
```

Comment: Thank you @Scott Hodgin , I will check on this code and update . Thanks for your help.

Comment: My miss @Scott , thank you much for the help , it fixed my issue and accepted it as answer,